# Calculation of modularity from sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, modularity, technical-debt

Is there a way to calculate modularity metric from the preexisting metrics in SonarQube? I want to calculate modularity so that I can use it for my technical debt calculation.

Comment: How do you define the modularity metric? Do you have a definition, a formula that can be applied?

Comment: By Modularity I mean the degree to which a product or solution is made up of components such that a change to one has minimal impact on another.Can this be captured by any of the SonarQube metric that can in turn help me define the modularity of the product. e.g. Something that has been defined in the following paper http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1309/1309.5689.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The Modularity of software is a composite metric. Thus, first you need to define the modularity and participating metrics. The paper you mentioned (http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1309/1309.5689.pdf) offers one of the ways. 
An alternative way is to detect modularity design smells and form a modularity metric formula (that uses the number of detected instances of modularity design smells). The modularity design smells are: Insufficient Modularization, Broken Modularization, Cyclically-dependent Modularization, and Hub-like Modularization (refer "Refactoring for software design smells").